# Generating a more meaningful error message when a Spock interaction fails?

Tags: groovy, spock

I am using Spock to verify that a method has been called once for each of a set of values:

```
def "something happens a lot"() {
  given:
    def foo = Mock(Foo)

  when: "call something one hundred times"
    doSomethingThisManyTimes(foo, 100)

  then: "verify something was invoked one hundred times, with correct argument"
    (1..100).each { 1 * foo.something(it) } 
}

private void doSomethingThisManyTimes(object,n) {
  (1..n).eachWithIndex { it, i -> 
    // Skip the third value
    if (i != 3) { 
       object.something(it) }
    }
}

interface Foo {
  void something(int n)
}
```

This performs the necessary verifications, but if there's a failure I get an unhelpful error message:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * foo.something(it)   (0 invocations)
```

Is there some way of generating a custom error message here, so that (for example) the following will be shown instead:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * foo.something(3)   (0 invocations)
```

I tried using an `assert`:

```
assert (1 * foo.something(it)) : "No something for ${it}"
```

but got a compiler error.

edit: changed `new Foo()` to `Mock(Foo)`

Comment: As far as I know there is no possibility for better info.

Comment: It isn't `def foo = Foo()`, is it? Also, are you really using a half-mock (i.e. a method on the object under test is mocked)?

Comment: That should be `Mock(Foo)` .. I am trying to translate the actual code into an example. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check the validity of arguments using assertions. For example, if it's tolerable/desirable to check the order of calls, you can do:

```
...
then:
(1..100).each { n -> 
    1 * foo.something(_) >> { int arg -> assert arg == n } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried that and got the following error message: `Too few invocations for:

    1 * foo.something{it} >> {
      args -> assert args == it : "no something for ${it}"
    }   (0 invocations)`

Comment: `foo.something{it}` is not what I proposed.